# Array.sort of a String containing three values Date, Time, and Time difference

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I have an array that contains the following

```
"Svr Conn: Start Time 03/03/2015 6:0:0 AM"
"Svr Conn: Stop Time 03/03/2015 6:07:08 AM Up Time 0:7:8"
^  Is the name of the event
         ^ Is Just text
                    ^ Is the Stop date
                               ^ Is the Stop Time
                                            ^ Is just text
                                                    ^ Is the length of time That the event was active.
```

Using the Array.Sort () It sorts by the first 03/03/2015
I have looked to find a way to sort by the Stop Date then Stop Time and then by Up time.  I could not find anything on how to do this.
I am looking to sort by 
Stop data, Stop Time, and then by Up time.
I would also like to have a button's or a list box to sort by the event or start time or stop time.

Comment: a string array cannot contain anything but strings.  it will not contain DateTime types or a time difference (whatever that is - TimeSpan?).  So when you sort it will sort using a Text compare where "9:30 AM" is greater than "11:45 PM" because the character "9" > "1"

Comment: Yes I understand That the strings are "strings" the date and time span have been added to that string.  I am looking for a way to sort by the different events and elements of that string.  Like
    Array.Sort(Myarray, {By string position x) or somthing like that.

Comment: when you glue it all together into one glob of string, they are no longer "different elements"  create a class for the 2-3 things, store them in a List and then you can sort by which element (property) you'd like

Comment: LogParser, baby.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659

Comment: @ Plutonix  How would I sort the list? Array.sort ? or is there a list sort? I am new to the list data source.

Comment: @ Dan-o  The LogParser is that a added extension  for VB?  How is it used I don't see ane example?  I have added code to create a Class and .Add to the list but I am stuck on how to sort..