# List not showing what is put in to the list

Tags: vb.net, list, class

I asked a Question and got an answer That I should be using a list.      It can be viewed here [Array.sort of a String containing three values Date, Time, and Time difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931445/array-sort-of-a-string-containing-three-values-date-time-and-time-difference?noredirect=1#comment46124481_28931445)

So I made a Class in my Class ? is this where I am going wrong?
What I need is to put the list into a Listbox or Datagridview and then have buttons to sort by Start time Stop time and such.  For now I am having problems just getting the list to show at all.

When I use the below code I get either
System.collection.generic.XXX
Or
The folder that the Vb file exists in and The String.join text XX
Like  FolderName.TimeLabelLBtest+LogTime

Here is the code for the Class

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Public Class TimeLabelLBtest
Inherits Label
Private m_VaraibleToSet As Boolean
<System.ComponentModel.Category("Control")> _
Public Property VaraibleToSet() As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_VaraibleToSet
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        m_VaraibleToSet = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_PrefixText As String = "Prefix Text"
<System.ComponentModel.Category("Control")> _
Public Property PrefixText() As String
    Get
        Return m_PrefixText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_PrefixText = value
    End Set
End Property


'***********************
Private Timer As Timer
Private ArrayTimer As Timer
Public StartTime As Date
Public StopTime As Date
Public AccTimeStg As String
Public TimeArray(19) As String
Private Ons As Boolean

Public Class LogTime
    ''Public EventName As String
    ''Public StartT As String
    ''Public StopT As String
    ''Public TSpan As String


    Private m_EventName As String
    Public Property EventName() As String
        Get
            Return m_EventName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_EventName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StartT As String
    Public Property StartT() As String
        Get
            Return m_StartT
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_StartT = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StopT As String
    Public Property StopT() As String
        Get
            Return m_StopT
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_StopT = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_TSpan As String
    Public Property TSpan() As String
        Get
            Return m_TSpan
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_TSpan = value
        End Set
    End Property
    '  Public Sub New( _
    'ByVal m_EventName As String, _
    'ByVal m_StartT As String, _
    'ByVal m_StopT As String, _
    'ByVal m_TSpan As String)
    '      EventName = m_EventName
    '      StartT = m_StartT
    '      StopT = m_StopT
    '      TSpan = m_TSpan
    '  End Sub
    Public Sub New( _
ByVal EventName As String, _
ByVal StartT As String, _
ByVal StopT As String, _
ByVal TSpan As String)

    End Sub
End Class


Public Sub New()
    Timer = New Timer
    Timer.Interval = 1
    AddHandler Timer.Tick, AddressOf Timer_Tick
    ArrayTimer = New Timer
    ArrayTimer.Interval = 100
    ArrayTimer.Enabled = True
    AddHandler ArrayTimer.Tick, AddressOf ArrayTimer_Tick
End Sub
Public TimeList As List(Of LogTime) = New List(Of LogTime)

Public Sub StartTimer()
    If Ons = False Then
        Ons = True
        StartTime = Now
        AddLog(TimeArray, PrefixText & ": Start Time " & StartTime)
        'AddLog(LogTime, PrefixText & ": Start Time " & StartTime)
        TimeList.Add(New LogTime(PrefixText, "Start Time " & StartTime, "", ""))
        Timer.Enabled = True
        Timer.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub StopTimer()
    If Ons = True Then
        Ons = False
        StopTime = Now
        AddLog(TimeArray, PrefixText & ": Stop Time " & StopTime & " Up Time " & AccTimeStg)
        TimeList.Add(New LogTime(PrefixText, "", "Stop Time " & StopTime, " Up Time " & AccTimeStg))
        Timer.Enabled = False
        Timer.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim TimeSpan As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(StartTime)
    AccTimeStg = TimeSpan.Hours & " : " & TimeSpan.Minutes & " : " & TimeSpan.Seconds
End Sub

Private Sub ArrayTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    ' ************************************
    ' where the problem is
    ' This returns 
    Me.Text = String.Join("XX", TimeList)

    ' FolderName.TimeLabelLBtest+LogTime
    ' Start or Stop sub called and then the Label looks like this
    ' FolderName.TimeLabelLBtest+LogTimexx' FolderName.TimeLabelLBtest+LogTime


    ' Need to use this to sort and get rid of the AddLog Sub
    'TimeList.Sort(Function(x, y) x.StartT.CompareTo(y.StopT))

    'Me.Text = PrefixText & " " & AccTimeStg
    ' this is the normal Me.text
End Sub
Private Sub AddLog(ByVal logAsArray() As String, ByVal newEntry As String)
    For index As Integer = logAsArray.Length - 1 To 1 Step -1
        logAsArray(index) = logAsArray(index - 1)
    Next
    logAsArray(0) = newEntry
End Sub


End Class
```

Here is the code that is in a timer and waits for the event to happen.

```
If SvrCommTrip And OneShot(10) = False Then
        OneShot(10) = True
        BtnTest1.Text = "Start"
        BtnTest2.Text = "Stop"
        LAtSvrComm.StartTimer()
    End If
    If SvrCommTrip = False And OneShot(10) = True Then
        OneShot(10) = False
        'countarry = countarry + 1
        'LAmysetcnt.Text = "MY Sett Count " & My.Settings.FirstString.Count
        LAtSvrComm.StopTimer()
        LBSvrConn.Items.Clear()
        If Not My.Settings.SvrConnStg Is Nothing Then
            My.Settings.SvrConnStg.Clear()
        End If
        For Idex = 0 To 19
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LAtSvrComm.TimeArray(Idex)) Then
                LBSvrConn.Items.Add(LAtSvrComm.TimeArray(Idex))
                My.Settings.SvrConnStg.Add(LAtSvrComm.TimeArray(Idex))
            End If
        Next


        LBListTest.Items.Clear()
        Dim ListStg As String
        Dim TList As Array
        TList = LAtSvrComm.TimeList.ToArray
        'For Each Obj As TimeLabelLBtest.LogTime In LAtSvrComm.TimeList
        For lk = 0 To LAtSvrComm.TimeList.Count - 1
            LBListTest.Items.Add(LAtSvrComm.TimeList.Item(lk))
        Next

        'For II = 0 To LAtSvrComm.TimeList.Count - 1
        Me.Text = LAtSvrComm.TimeList(0).ToString
        '    LBListTest.Items.Add(ListStg)
        'Next

        My.Settings.Save()
        'If countarry = My.Settings.SvrConnStg.Count Then
        'countarry = 0
        ' End If
    End If

    If PLC_TmrFault = False And OneShot(11) = False And RcvTmr.Enabled Then
        OneShot(11) = True
        LAtPLC.StartTimer()
    End If

    If PLC_TmrFault And OneShot(11) = True Then
        OneShot(11) = False
         My.Settings.FirstString.Count
        LAtPLC.StopTimer()
        LBPLCCom.Items.Clear()
        If Not My.Settings.PLCCommStg Is Nothing Then
            My.Settings.PLCCommStg.Clear()
        End If
        For Idex = 0 To 19
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(LAtPLC.TimeArray(Idex)) Then
                LBPLCCom.Items.Add(LAtPLC.TimeArray(Idex))
                My.Settings.PLCCommStg.Add(LAtPLC.TimeArray(Idex))
            End If
        Next
        My.Settings.Save()
                End If
```

I am new to the list and collection stuff in my VB experience.. So let me know if there is anything I should read up on or need to understand first Thx

Comment: I'm guessing the ListBox is showing the TypeName like `WindowsApplication1.LogTime"?  Override the `ToString` method on `LogTime` and tell it what you want to display - given a class object Windows has no idea what should show.  Then rather than adding items from a List<T> to a ListBox just set it as the DataSource

Comment: @Plutonix  I tried the suggested method of removing the To String in my code outside of the Class.    The result now shows Collection in the ListBox any time the event is triggered.  Will try to add the DataSource In a bit when I get a chance.

Comment: I added the DataSource "LogTime" and nothing populated the ListBox     It Would not let me add a DataSource of my LBSvrComm.TimeList??